# good (noSQL?) database for physical measurements

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb, replication, key-value-store

We're building a measurement system that will eventually consist of thousands of measurement stations. Each station will save around 500 million measurements consisting of 30 scalar values over its lifetime. These will be float values. We're now wondering how to save this data on each station, considering we'll be building a web app on each station such that

- we want to visualize the data on multiple timescales (eg measurements of one week, month, year)
- we need to build moving averages over the data (eg average over a month to show in a year graph)
- the database needs to be crash resistant (power outages)
- we are only doing writes and reads, no updates or deletes on the data

additionally we'd like one more server that can show the data of, say, 1000 measurement stations. That would be ~50TB of data in 500 billion measurements. To transmit the data from measurement station to server, I thought that some type of database-level replication would be a clean and efficient way.

Now I'm wondering if a noSQL solution might be better than mySQL for these purposes. Especially **couchDB**, **Cassandra** and maybe key-value stores like **Redis** look appealing to me. Which of those would suit the "measurement time series" data model best in your opinion? What about other advantages like crash-safety and replication from measurement station to main server?

Comment: I've also found NetCDF - anyone got experience with this one? It is made for time series, but I'm not sure about crash resistancy and scaling using multiple servers...

Answer (score 3):

I think CouchDB is a great database -- but it's ability to deal with large data is questionable. CouchDB's primary focus is on simplicity of development and offline replication, not necessarily on performance or scalability. CouchDB itself does not support partitioning, so you'll be limited by the maximum node size unless you use BigCouch or invent your own partitioning scheme.

No foolin, Redis is an in-memory database. It's extremely fast and efficient at getting data in and out of RAM. It does have the ability to use disk for storage, but it's not terribly good at it. It's great for bounded quantities of data that change frequently. Redis does have replication, but does not have any built-in support for partitioning, so again, you'll be on your own here.

You also mentioned Cassandra, which I think is more on target for your use case. Cassandra is well suited for databases that grow indefinitely, essentially it's original use case. The partitioning and availability is baked in so you won't have to worry about it very much. The data model is also a bit more flexible than the average key/value store, adding a second dimension of columns, and can practically accomodate millions of columns per row. This allows time-series data to be "bucketed" into rows that cover time ranges, for example. The distribution of data across the cluster (partitioning) is done at the row level, so only one node is necessary to perform operations within a row.

Hadoop plugs right into Cassandra, with "native drivers" for MapReduce, Pig, and Hive, so it could potentially be used to aggregate the collected data and materialize the running averages. The best practice is to shape data around queries, so probably want to store multiple copies of the data in "denormalized" form, one for each type of query.

Check out this post on doing time-series in Cassandra:

http://rubyscale.com/2011/basic-time-series-with-cassandra/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out a bit more on Cassandra and maybe drop the CouchDB idea...

Answer (score 2):

For highly structured data of this nature (time series of float vectors) I tend to shy away from databases all together.  Most of the features of a database aren't very interesting; you basically aren't interested in things like atomicity or transactional semantics.  The only feature that *is* desirable is resilience to crashing.  That feature, however, is trivially easy to implement when you don't ever need to *undo* a write (no updates/deletes), just by appending to a file.  crash recovery is simple; open a new file with an incremented serial number in the filename.

A logical format for this is plain-old csv. after each measurement is taken, call `flush()` on the underlying `file`.  Getting the data replicated back to the central server is a job efficiently solved by `rsync(1)`.  You can then import the data in the analysis tool of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would persionally shy away from "csv" and "plaintext" files. These are convenient when you have low volume and want to skip the tools to quickly look at the data or make small alterations to the data.

When you're talking about "50Tb" of data, that's quite a lot. If a simple trick will reduce that by a factor of two, that will pay itself back in storage costs and bandwidth charges.

If the measurements are taken on a regular basis that would mean that instead of saving the timestamp with every measurement, you store the start time and interval and just store the measurments.

I'd go for a file format that has a small header and then just a bunch of floating point measurements. To prevent files getting really really large, decide on a maximum file size. If you initiallize the file by fully writing it before starting to use the file, it will be completely allocated on the disk by the time you start to use it. Now you can mmap the file and alter the data. If power goes down when you are changing the data, it simply either makes it to disk or it doesn't.